# Null spaces associated to eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $f$ is an endomorphism in a finite dimensional vector space,  and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$. Let $C_f = \text{det}(f - X \,\text{Id})$ be the characteristic polynomial of $f$, and $M_f$ the minimal polynomial of $f$.

If $p$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $M_f$, it can be shown that
$$
N(f-\lambda \text{Id}) \subsetneq N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^2 \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^p = N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^{p+1} .
$$

Is there a relation between the dimensions of $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})$, $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^2$, $\dots$, $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^p$ ?

That is, if $G$ is the supplementary of $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})$ in $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^p$, do the vectors of $G$ appear in a regular way through the $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})$, $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^2$, $\dots$, $N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^p$ ?

My teacher said that $\text{dim}\,N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^k + 1 = \text{dim}\,N(f-\lambda \text{Id})^{k+1}$, for all $1 \le k < p $, but has then retracted himself. Such relationships might be useful (say for calculating $p$ given $\text{dim}\,N(f-\lambda \text{Id})$) and $C_f$), but I fail to see how they can be studied, other than by looking at examples.

P.S. I am translating the notations from french, so feel free to tell me if adjustments are necessary.

Comment: Look for nilpotent Endomorphisms if ur intrested. Example, the matrix :
  \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can deduce the Jordan form of the matrix based on how $\dim(N(f - \lambda I)^k)$ increases with the exponent $k$.

In particular,
$$
\dim(N(f - \lambda I)^{k}) - \dim(N(f - \lambda I)^{k-1})
$$
is precisely the number of Jordan blocks associated with $\lambda$ that have size at least $k$.

---

As an example:

$$
f = \pmatrix{
0&1\\
&0&1\\
&&0\\
&&&0&1\\
&&&&0\\
&&&&&0\\
&&&&&&0}
$$
we have $C_f(x) = x^3$ and
$$
\dim(N(f^{1})) - \dim(N(f^0)) = 4\\
\dim(N(f^{2})) - \dim(N(f^1)) = 3\\
\dim(N(f^{3})) - \dim(N(f^2)) = 2\\
\dim(N(f^{k})) - \dim(N(f^{k-1})) = 0 \quad \forall k \geq 4
$$